# Code is giving `null` error for a new window opened using JavaScript to close it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a close a window in JavaScript. It opens just fine. However, I cannot close it because the reference to the new Window somehow becomes null in the code. Here is my code:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="javascript:closeOnLoad('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');">Click to open popup</a> it will close automatically after five seconds.</p>
  <script>
  function closeOnLoad(myLink)
{
  var newWindow = window.open(myLink, "connectWindow", "width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes");
  setTimeout(
             function()
             {
               newWindow.close();
             },
            1000
            );
  return false;
}
</script>
```

When I open the page in browser and click the link, I get the following error:

```
newWindow is null
```

Why am I getting this error?

UPDATE:

I tested it in other browsers. It seems like the code does not work only in Firefox. (I have Firefox 75).

Comment: A pop-up blocker blocks the window in FF.

Comment: @Teemu The window opens but it does not close.

Comment: Just switch off the pop-up blocker, and you'll find your code to work in FF too. Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gt25pvuw/) in my FF75. Notice, that you don't need `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in the onclick attribute, just remove it (that doesn't affect on the code execution, though).

Comment: Just change the setTimeout(function()... ) to setTimeout(()=>... ) this way the browser will know it is on the same scope of the function

Comment: @tomerraitz The outer variable scope is always accessible, nevetheless the used function type, you're mixing scopes and contexts here.

Comment: @Teemu you may be right, but this is still the answer for him, you can check yourself in fireFox

Comment: @tomerraitz But I already checked OP's code in FF, as stated in one of my previous comments, the "_code works fine_".